# Replace day of a date in a dataframe column

Tags: python

I have created a dataframe with a range of dates from 8/1/18 to today() and am trying to assign a month_start_date to each date (eg: 2018/08/04 would be 2018/08/01).

I have been able to get the day of the date into month_start_date, but I'm really just trying to replace the day in the date column with 1 for all dates.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

datelist = pd.date_range(start='2018-08-01', end=datetime.today())

df_columns = ['date']
df = pd.DataFrame(datelist, columns = df_columns)

df['month_start_date'] = df['date'].dt.day
print(df)
```

```py
          date  month_start_date
0   2018-08-01                 1
1   2018-08-02                 2
2   2018-08-03                 3
3   2018-08-04                 4
4   2018-08-05                 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df['month_start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this more generally with the Pandas.tseries.offsets package. In this example you can calculate your dates using [MonthBegin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin.html)

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

datelist = pd.date_range(start='2018-08-01',end=datetime.datetime.today())
month_start_list = (datelist + datetime.timedelta(1)) + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(n=-1)
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": datelist, "month_start": month_start_list})
print(df)
```

```
          date month_start
0   2018-08-01  2018-08-01
1   2018-08-02  2018-08-01
2   2018-08-03  2018-08-01
3   2018-08-04  2018-08-01
4   2018-08-05  2018-08-01
..         ...         ...
892 2021-01-09  2021-01-01
893 2021-01-10  2021-01-01
894 2021-01-11  2021-01-01
895 2021-01-12  2021-01-01
896 2021-01-13  2021-01-01

[897 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This is interesting and can be helpful for sure, but a couple things maybe you can help me address:
(1) I noticed that this data is almost producing the desired result, but actually adding a month (see that the dataframe starts at 2018-09-01, when it should read 2018-08-01.
(2) I was looking to add a new column with this value so that each individual date is assigned a month_start_date

Comment: Here are few things that might help:

1. MonthBegin takes an input, n, which is the number of months to roll backwards or forwards. By default its taking a value of 1, but to roll back to the start of the current month you can set n=-1. You will also notice there is a edge case at the start of the month. Pandas moves every date, so it would roll back to the prior month. To avoid this you can add pd.Timedelta(days=1) first.

2. The output of the addition won't modify the original input, so you can just specify it as a separate column.

I'll edit my code above with the changes.

Comment: Actually to keep your types consistent, instead of pd.Timedelta, you should use datetime.datetime.timedelta(1)

Comment: That was super helpful, thank you so much for the clarification!