# Perform date transformation before multple groupbys in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I wish to groupby date country and type and convert any date that has same month value to the first of that month.

**Data**

```
country     type    date        energy  
US          aa      8/5/2022    10  
US          aa      8/25/2022   1   
US          aa      8/2/2022    11  
US          bb      8/5/2022    55  
US          bb      8/15/2022   25  
AUSTRALIA   bb      9/15/2022   5
```

**Desired**

```
step 1: convert all dates to 1st of the month values
step 2: groupby country type and date sum energy 

        


country     type    date         energy 
US          aa      8/1/2022    22  
US          bb      8/1/2022    80  
AUSTRALIA   bb      9/1/2022    5
```

**Doing**

```
df.date - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
df.groupby(['country','type','date'], as_index=False).agg({'energy': sum})
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65708648/3268228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using `pd.Grouper`:

```
df.groupby(['country', 
            'type', 
            pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='MS')], sort=False)['energy'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     country type       date  energy
0         US   aa 2022-08-01      22
1         US   bb 2022-08-01      80
2  AUSTRALIA   bb 2022-09-01       5
```